# Devexpress ASPXUploader UploadedFiles.Count is Always 1

Tags: c#, asp.net, file-upload, devexpress

```
void SaveFiles(out XElement Attachments)
    {
        Attachments = null;
        if (Uploader1.UploadedFiles.Count() > 0)
        {
            Attachments = new XElement("files");
            foreach (var file in Uploader1.UploadedFiles)
            {
                string ext = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(file.FileName).ToLower();
                string FileName = System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file.FileName) + "_" + Guid.NewGuid().ToString().Substring(0, 4) + ext;
                Attachments.Add(new XElement("file", FileName));
                file.SaveAs(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "upload\\support\\" + FileName);
            }
        }
    }
```

And markup

```
<dx:ASPxUploadControl ID="Uploader1" runat="server" Width="280px">
    <AdvancedModeSettings EnableMultiSelect="True" />
</dx:ASPxUploadControl>
```

regardless i choose multiple files or even nothing at all here count is alway 1.
**is it correct way to get files by UploadedFiles?**

Comment: Why don't you contact the DX guys regarding your issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is necessary to handle the **ASPxUploadControl.FileUploadComplete** event and retrieve the posted file(s) via the event's arguments.

Take a look at [this](http://demos.devexpress.com/ASPxperienceDemos/UploadControl/MultiFileSelection.aspx) demo to see this functionality in action.